# Symfony firewalls pattern doesnt match

Tags: symfony

I have weird problem with symfony security.yml

```
providers:
     main:
        entity: { class: AppBundle\Entity\User, property: apiKey }

firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
       pattern: ^/
       anonymous: ~
       guard:
           authenticators:
             - app.token_authenticator
```

when i access to `domen` only that fire the token_authenticator and that is ok, then i change pattern in main firewall to `^/api` but any off `domen/api | domen/api/ | domen/apissdads` trigger token_authenticator, I also try with 
`pattern: ^/api$` but is same. Only works with `^/`.

I also get error

```
throw 0 < count($allow) ? new MethodNotAllowedException(array_unique($allow)) : new ResourceNotFoundException();
```

This is image from [Symfony Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWt42.png) but i change `pattern: ^/api`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you change path in `pattern` of main firewall it still will use `token_authenticator` but only for paths that comply to your regular expression. And that's correct behaviour. If you need for `/api` path not use `token_authenticator` you can create another firewall for that.

Comment: I try to use `token_authenticator` like this `security:
    providers:
         main:
            entity: { class: AppBundle\Entity\User, property: apiKey }
    firewalls:
        dev:
          pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
          security: false
        main:
           pattern: ^/api
           security: true
           anonymous: ~
           guard:
               authenticators:
                 - app.token_authenticator` but when i go to `/api` doesnt trigger `token_authenticator`;`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
main:
   pattern: ^/domen/api
```

Can you try that and see if that works?

---

Maybe try this under firewalls:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/domen/api, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Also, i presume you've setup [file permissions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html)?

Comment: No, is the same error! I also clear cache but nothing. If something mean i got error in `var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php at line 122`!